# async mount for read-only filesystem?

Tags: mount, openbsd

It seems OpenBSD's /usr/X11R6 is only written when I upgrade the base system (specifically, the X11 sets). For regular use cases, I want to speed up every read of /usr/X11R6. I wanted to mount the partition containing X11 files read-only and with the flag async.
From mount(8):

> This is a dangerous flag to set since it does not
> guarantee to keep a consistent file system structure
> on the disk.  You should not use this flag unless you
> are prepared to recreate the file system should your
> system crash.  The most common use of this flag is to
> speed up restore(8) where it can give a factor of two
> speed increase.

But since I'm mounting the filesystem read-only, should there be any issue about inconsistent fs structer (write to disk is not completed)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. Just remember to switch to `rw` before upgrading.

Comment: But I think async mount flags shouldn't increase read speed, only write speed.. (the write operation returned before the write is actually complete), so there is no reason using async + ro?

Comment: That's a different question :) I'd say probably not, but "the proof is in the pudding", it's something you can easily test...